# ¿Como eliminar caracteres o numero duplicados y ordenarlos usando expresiones regulares?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código;

```
String str = "A49B455HK11GTY11P";     

          str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");

               List<String> lista = Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" "));
               lista.stream().distinct();
               Collections.sort(lista);
               System.out.println(lista);
```

Pero no consigo eliminar los números duplicados ni ordenarlos en orden ascendente.

Answer (score 0):

No estas usando correctamente el método `distinct`. Debes asignar el resultado a una nueva lista.

Para ello, tienes que usar el método `collect()` y devolver el valor a una lista:

```
List<String> strings = lista.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Además, estas ordenando una lista de `String` y no de `Integer`, por lo que debes pasar los valores a una lista de `Integer`:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String s : strings) integers.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
```

Y ya si puedes ordenar e imprimir esta nueva lista:

```
Collections.sort(integers);
System.out.println(integers);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tú ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo una solución alternativa, se basa en crear la lista de integer comprobando si existe el valor con la función contains y una vez realizado se ordena.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class stackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "A49B455HK11GTY11P";
        str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");

        List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> lista = Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" "));
        for (String stringValue : lista) {
            if (!integerList.contains(Integer.parseInt(stringValue)))
                integerList.add(Integer.parseInt(stringValue));
        }
        Collections.sort(integerList);
        System.out.println(integerList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por plantear tú alternativa.